# Show that $\max_{\bar \Omega} |u|=\max_{\partial \Omega} |u|$.

Tags: analysis, partial-differential-equations, maximum-principle

Let $\Omega$ denote the unbounded set $|x|>1$. Let $u \in C^2(\bar \Omega)$, $\Delta u=0$ in $\Omega$ and $\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty} u(x)=0$. Show that $\max_{\bar \Omega} |u|=\max_{\partial \Omega} |u|$.

So, applying maximum principle is an obvious choice, but it seems obvious with the principle, even without the limit condition. So I think I must have missed something. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Well, take $u(x, y) = x$ and notice that it's $C^2$ and harmonic, and the desired inequality is false. So the limit condition is indeed necessary.

Comment: The way that this counterexample works is because there's a boundary point that you haven't considered, namely $\infty$. But the limiting condition says....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any unbounded harmonic function on $\mathbb{R}^n$ shows why the limiting condition is necessary; for example, $u(x_1, ..., x_n) = x_1$. The issue here is that there is another part of the boundary, the point at infinity. This is easier to visualize if you think of $\mathbb{R}^2$ and the Riemann sphere, for example.

This should indicate how to proceed with the proof. Spoilers below.

> So the maximum is attained on the boundary, and the value at infinity is zero after we extend the function to make sense there. If $f$ is identically zero, we're done. Else, the maximum doesn't occur at infinity.